# Template not found in Django while trying to integrate Twitter and Facebook.

Tags: python, django, facebook, templates, django-templates

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/**

```
registration/login.htm


Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Python27\django\demo_email\APPemail\template\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\django\demo_email\demo_email\registration\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\captcha\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_facebook-5.2.6-py2.7.egg\django_facebook\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
```

**Error view**
      Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://netch.pagekite.me/accounts/login/
**i am using local tp public server**

Django Version: 1.5.2
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_countries',
 'captcha',
 'django_facebook',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'APPemail')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django_facebook.middleware.FacebookCanvasMiddleWare')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Python27\django\demo_email\APPemail\template\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\django\demo_email\demo_email\registration\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\captcha\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_facebook-5.2.6-py2.7.egg\django_facebook\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\login.html (File does not exist)
```

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  140.                     response = response.render()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  80.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in resolve_template
  58.             return loader.get_template(template)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  146.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in find_template
  139.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: registration/login.html
```

**How can I solve this error?**

**i tried django-facebook 5.2.6.**

but it's giving me error when i call /accounts/login
   error
   TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
   registration/login.htm****

Comment: You don't have to scream.

Comment: Did you setup your templates folder in settings.py? Where is located your login.html? The error is pretty clear, it cannot find the file. Check whether or not it is at the expected location.

Comment: #### i am using django facebook 5.2.6 package,went through docs when i am calling url /accounts/login then i am getting this error@AKS1

Comment: Yes, but sorry I don't know the source coee by heart. As I said the error is pretty self-explanatory.